# How to convert unix-epoch to human time in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, epoch

In the Tableau, I have a column containing  the timestamps in unix-time format, which I wish to convert it to Human time.
Is it possible to use R script in Calculated Field for such time conversion?

[Tableau screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNaXE.jpg)

Comment: No need to use R for this, call dateadd()

Answer (score 8):

I think you should create a new calculated field like this:

New_date = dateadd('second',[Time],#1970-01-01#)

Or if [Time] is in milliseconds then just divide it by 1000 to convert to seconds before passing it to dateadd of course

Comment: thanks! your solution worked well. But still wondering  why 
New_date=DATE(DATEADD('second', [Time], #1970-01-01#))
didn't work when connecting to **mysql** (adding **DATE** function at the beginning), but when connecting to **csv**, or **xlsx** it worked!